# How does TTL of package changes?

Tags: ipv4, packet-path

Consider a following scheme:

```
Server(TTL=64) <--> RouterA(TTL=64) <--> RouterB(TTL=64) <--> Desktop(TTL=128)
```

The Desktop sends a package to the Server, this package on the netowrk card of desktop has ttl equal to 128. What would be TTL of the package when it will pass RouterB - 127, 64 or 63 ?

Is there any way to test it? I'm using Linux and run command `ping google.com -t 100`, but I recieve only TTL of response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ttl(time to live) value will depend of the initial value of your ttl field(that is depending of your operatins system).

Here you can find some common values:

https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/58345

If you are using windows(not 95 version)127 will be your result because it is just one jump has happens, the ttl value change(decrease) on the way that a packes passes by one router or some devices betwenn 2 networks. On that way, once the packet get into router b, and it forwarded to router A, on that moment the ttl value is dereceased by one.